# Can't Install Provisioning Profile on iPhone

Tags: xcode, xcode5, code-signing, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I'm developing an iOS app and I've been testing on my iPad so far. As the app is almost finished I tried to test it on my iPhone but I can't install the provisioning profile in it.

These are the steps I did: (Xcode 5)

```
1) While my iPad was connected to mac I plugged in my iPhone

2) Device was recognized, then I hit the button "Use for development"

3) An error about not having a valid developer ID appear.

4) Then I went to Xcode preferences -> Accounts and I found out there was 2 account for my user (maybe Xcode created another user since I had two simultaneously connected devices?)

5) I then deleted the dummy account, checked the provisioning profile in the portal (it has the 2 devices added to it), opened organizer and clicked on "Add to Member Center" to redownload it but nothing came.

6) I refreshed the profile in User Accounts. Tried to download it again, nothing.

7) I also noticed that the iPad has two entries of the same provisioning profile on from may, when I started developing, and another for today. The iPhone has none.
```

One thing worth noting is that although I have 2 devices added to the profile I only have 1 certificate (is it correct?)

[image: provisioning profile]
[image: portal]
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check in Apple's web portal if the iPhone's device ID is registered there?

Comment: Yes, it is. Under the devices Tab both the iPad and iPhone are registered with the correct ID.

Comment: What is the error when you are installing using xcode ?

Comment: Just fixed the issue by rebooting the mac. When I tried to deploy Xcode presented a message saying an incorrect ID has been assigned and a button to "fix issue"

Answer (score 1):

It seem to be a Xcode problem. I reboot the mac and next time it presented a message saying an incorrect ID was assigned and an button with a "fix issue" label.

After fixing the issue Xcode downloaded the profile again and it worked.